# Docbook-XML, Webhelp and XSLT / Xalan error

Tags: xml, xslt, docbook, xalan

Processing a xml test file of 11907 lines total 325.050 bytes.

```
D:\projekte\dashboard>ant webhelp

Buildfile: D:\projekte\dashboard\build.xml

validate:

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\projekte\dashboard\docs

chunk:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\projekte\dashboard\docs
     [xslt] Processing D:\projekte\dashboard\dashboard.xml to D:\projekte\dashboard\docs\null1967716666
     [xslt] Loading stylesheet d:\apps\docbook-xsl-1.78.1\profiling\profile.xsl
     [xslt] Warning:  org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.
     [xslt] Warning:  org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser: Property 'http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/entityExpansionLimit' is not recognized.
     [xslt] Warning:  org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.
     [xslt] Warning:  org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser: Property 'http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/entityExpansionLimit' is not recognized.
     [xslt] Warning:  org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.
     [xslt] Warning:  org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser: Property 'http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/entityExpansionLimit' is not recognized.
     [xslt] : Error! Keine weiteren DTM-IDs verfügbar
     [xslt] Failed to process D:\projekte\dashboard\dashboard.xml
```

After some googling I found:

```
ER_NO_DTMIDS_AVAIL,
       "Keine weiteren DTM-IDs verf\u00fcgbar"},
```

Which leads me to http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/faq.html#faq-N10340
Trying to determine which version of Xalan is used http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/faq.html#environmentcheck doesn't work for me.

After some googling again I found:

`java com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.EnvironmentCheck`

```
#---- BEGIN writeEnvironmentReport($Revision: 1.10 $): Useful stuff found: ----
java.version=1.8.0
version.xalan2x=not-present
version.JAXP=1.4
java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
version.SAX=2.0
version.crimson=not-present
java.class.path=.
version.ant=not-present
sun.boot.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\classes
version.DOM=3.0
version.xalan1=not-present
version.xalan2_2=Xalan Java 2.7.0
version.xerces2=Xerces-J 2.7.1
version.xerces1=not-present
#----- END writeEnvironmentReport: Useful properties found: -----
# YAHOO! Your environment seems to be OK.
```

If I reduce the file size < 300k the file gets processed.

Where is my fault?

**Update 2014-03-23**

I'm using a build.properties file which is located in the webhelp folder (d:\apps\docbook-xsl-1.78.1\webhelp)

```
...
xslt-processor-classpath=d:\\apps\\saxon\\saxon.jar
xercesImpl.jar=d:\\apps\\xerces-2_11_0\\xercesImpl.jar
xml-apis.jar=d:\\apps\\xerces-2_11_0\\xml-apis.jar
...
```

This options should be included with `<import file="d:\\apps\\docbook-xsl-1.78.1\\webhelp\\build.xml"/>` in the build file which I use for processing.

What do I have to setup in the build.properties to use the correct tools?

Answer (score 0):

Use the version of Xalan from Apache in preference to the version embedded in the JDK. The version in the JDK is very old and buggy.

Better still, use Saxon...

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use Saxon 6.5.5 instead of Xalan to transform documents with DocBook Webhelp. You can find more info on how to use Saxon with webhelp in the SO answer, [DocBook-XML and webhelp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22497904/388714).

Comment: The link you reference points to my original question ;) I'm not sure why this error occurs, please see my updated question.